# mousewheel to advance the eye view on a vector

Tags: c#, math, game-engine

I'm trying to implement a mousewheel zoom effect in my game. And for my eye view I got vertex `A[-75, 125, -500]` and a center vertex which the eye focuses on `B[500, 0, 500]`

between the two vertex I guess I have some sorta vector, which I should use to achieve the desired zooming effect.

```
AB = B - A.
Vector AB = [575, 125, 1000]
```

So having the vector AB I'm thinking I can move A along the vector AB

```
A = (500 - x, 0 - y, 500 - z) = (575, 125, 1000)
```

I'm getting stuck here, not knowing wether my so far methods are even correct. And would appreciate any help.

Comment: You would need the formula A' = A + AB * factor, factor going from 0 to 1

Comment: Zooming means narrowing the field of view while keeping the eye point static, not moving the eye point closer to a point